# Is this floating point behavior or a bug in PHP?

Tags: php, debugging, floating-point

**CLARIFYING: This isn't asking why I'm getting rounding errors.  I understand this is a mistake or an oversight.  The question asks why it prints as whole in the first var_dump, but casting acts as if it were 57916.9repeating and truncates said .9repeating.**

The following occurs:

You take a string (or float -- does not matter) that contains the value 579.17 and multiply it 100.  It var_dumps the expected 57917.  Not 57916.99999999999999999999999 or similar. var_dump should not be rounding anything as a debugging function in my opinion. It may have to truncate, but rounding is unexpected in a debugging function.

However, if one then casts that to an integer, you get an unexpected 57916 from var_dump.

I'm aware of issues with floating point numbers, but the act of casting a floating point number that prints as exactly 57917 in PHP apparently effectively subtracts 1.  This is a very small number.

This only appears to happen for some numbers, such as 579.17.  It does not occur for others I've tested. All we're doing is multiplying a number by 100 to send to an API that expects cents. The API library understandably casts to integer since the API doesn't accept fractional cents.

Test case:

```
php -r '$n = ("579.17" * 100); var_dump($n, (int)$n);'
```

Output:

```
float(57917)
int(57916)
```

Environment:

```
x86-32,
x86-64 both.
```

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Thanks. I know about floating point oddities like that. What I don't understand is that var_dump prints 57917, not something weird like 57916.99999999999999999999999999. And when I cast it, it seems it were. Nothing is asking var_dump to round. I would never expect var_dump to round anything. Just like decimals, FPs can't represent everything, and this was an oversight in the code to change dollars+cents to cents, but I find this exact case puzzling since it prints as if it were whole until after the cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var_dump` uses [`precision`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) from php.ini to display float value. You could raise it to see what happens.

```
php -r 'ini_set("precision", 20); $n = ("579.17" * 100); var_dump($n, (int)$n);'
// double(57916.999999999992724)
// int(57916)
```

Also. There is no matter x86 or x64. PHP uses 64 bits for floats.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: Hm. So effectively PHP _is_ rounding it when you print it and it's going to round after however many 9s it takes to consume the resolution in the 'precision' setting?  But it does not do this when you cast. Unless I'm missing something, I don't think var_dump() should round under any circumstances. It's a debugging function.

Comment: Yes. Precision uses for rounding while displaying.

Comment: Accepted and +1'd. I'm still not sure var_dump() should be doing any rounding. There are certain numbers floats _can_ represent, and others it cannot. This muddies things even more than they usually are for floating point arithmetic.

Comment: debug_zval_dump even honors this ini setting.  Not that I'd ever do this, but php -r '$n = ("579.17" * 100); var_dump($n, (int)"$n");' and php -r '$n = ("579.17" * 100); var_dump($n, (int) (string) $n);' also work 'as expected.' Precision is an implicit rounding function that is used even in debugging functions. Maybe there should be a higher default for all debugging functions.

Comment: @JaimieSirovich: if `var_dump()` did no rounding at all, it would end up showing (for example) `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` for `0.1`, and `1.00000000000000001999189980260288361964776078853415942018260300593659569925554346761767628861329298958274607481091185079852827053974965402226843604196126360835628314127871794272492894246908066589163059300043457860230145025079449986855914338755579873208034769049845635890960693359375E-100` for `1e-100`.  I doubt that's really what users want.

Comment: @MarkDickinson In var_dump? That (chopped after ~20 digits or the latter) would be what I want while _debugging_. Truncation and exponential form might be OK. But I'm not sure '57917' for 57916.999999999999999999999999 is OK in a debugging function.

Comment: @MarkDickinson , `var_dump` uses `precision`. You see all those numbers hence your precision settings raised.

Comment: @JaimieSirovich: Fair enough; I see truncation as just another form of rounding, though;  I'm not sure why one would be acceptable while the other wouldn't.

Comment: @MarkDickinson The silent rounding made debugging less obvious in this case, and var_dump is meant for debugging. I was faced with a situation where the seemingly impossible happened. A library I passed fake-67917 casted the variable to an integer and it changed inside the library to 67916. That library wanted number of pennies (maybe for reasons like this), not dollars and cents — OK multiply by 100. According to var_dump, I was passing 67917. The invoices were getting billed 1 penny less sometimes, and the bug was very frustrating to find since it only happened for certain exact values.

Comment: @JaimieSirovich , there is one rule about money and floats. Do not store money within floats.

Comment: @sectus Yeah, and it was coming from a bunch of fixed point calculations from SQL. Think about how easy that is to overlook. You just write ($row['total'] * 100). Boom. bcmul($row['total'], 100) is much less charming. Maybe this particular case is not so common, but it was non-obvious. If var_dump dumped 67916.9999999 it would have been made more obvious and bcmul would have been there before I had to insert debugging code in another library or use an actual debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Use `round()` instead of `int()`. The actual value of `579.17 * 100` is something like `57916.99999`. `var_dump()` shows this as `57917`, but when you use `int()` it truncates the fraction. Using `round()` will go to the nearest integer, rather than always truncating down.

Comment: That's actually what we ended up doing.  I'm wondering if this would happen in any language and is hardware specific.  It's particularly weird because it only happens on some numbers, but not all, and that var_dump doesn't print .9repeating.

Comment: It's endemic to floating point, and will happen in most languages. The reason it only happens with some numbers is that some of them have errors on the high side, so they might be 57817.0000001, which rounds down as you expect.

Comment: Read the link that was posted above in the comments.

Comment: I've met FP issues before.  I know you can't depend on equality.  I've never seen one where it prints as a whole number without rounding, but isn't when you cast it.  Maybe I just didn't notice it.  This example is not in the guide, and is very counterintuitive.

Comment: When you print a floating point number it tries to be helpful by printing the simplest number that has the same internal representation, which causes it to be rounded. That hides inaccuracies like this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "same internal representation?"  It would seem that using bcmul() is probably the most correct thing to do since this is a value with a known number of precision (2 decimal places) and there is no 'money' or fixed point type in PHP. The 579.17 itself comes from fixed point calculations in MySQL.

Comment: Floating point numbers are approximate, they actually represent a range of values. 579.17, 579.1699999999999, and 579.17000000001 all might be encoded with the same floating point value. The same with `57917, 57916.99999999, and 57917.00000001`. So when you ask it to print the number, it picks the shortest value from the range of values.

Comment: What is var_dump _doing_ that casting is not to reconcile that?  Could it (PHP? I'm not using any formatting functions) not do that same operation on the cast, or would that not be a simple cast anymore?

Comment: `var_dump()` is printing the shortest number whose floating point representation is the internal value that was given. In this case, it happens to be the nearest integer. `int()` just discards any fraction in the internal number, so it rounds down.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not understanding you. It looks like the 'precision' ini setting is at issue here as another user commented. PHP is rounding silently in the function that prints a floating point number to the screen. I'm not sure this is a bug in PHP, but it does lead to oversights and gotchas. What happened is we accidentally overlooked that a fixed point calculation from MySQL was casted to a float and we simply multiplied by 100 to send it to an API that wants cents. Very easy mistake to make.  var_dump is the go-to for debugging. Even debug_zval_dump() ignores the ini setting and rounds.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because hardware cannot truly and accurately express floating point numbers. So what appears as 579.17 is actually more like 579.16999999. So when you multiply it and cast it as an int it truncates the decimal leaving you with 57916.

Comment: I had a similar bug in C where only numbers that ended in a 4 caused this error, but nothing else.

Comment: Did it actually print as a whole number when it was a float and then only result in rounding weirdness when you casted?  That's what seems the weirdest here.

Comment: Yes it was exactly that. Weird indeed.